# How to change appearance of an Empty

Tags: workflow

I have a complex scene with lot of Empties. For a better survey I would like to change the appearance of an already created empty.

Just in case:
How to change the appearance of several Empties simultaneously?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

### Change a single Empty

- Select the desired *Empty*
- Go the *Properties* Panel
- Click on the *Data* tab
- Change the *Display* property

[image]

### Change multiple Empties

- Select the desired *Empties*
- Change the *Display* property (this will only effect the active *Empty*)
- Right-click <kbd>RMB</kbd> on the *Display* property and choose: *Copy To Selected*

[image]
*You can also adjust the size of the Empties in exactly the same way*

**Note**: You can also have other 'object types' than *Empties* in your selection while changing the *Display Type*. ***Copy To Selected*** will only effect objects of the same 'object type'. 
 [image]

Answer (score 10):

In addition to using *Copy to Selected* to change the empties' size and shape, you can also <kbd>Alt</kbd>+Left-Click on a property to change if for all selected objects in real time.

[image]

In this clip I am holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> as I change the icon shape and size.

Comment: useful addition thx

Comment: Wow, that's really trick.  I wish I'd known that a while back.

Comment: This changed my life :)